# VBA code stops after loop with RefreshLink

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

The following code updates the links between my tables and selected backend. I have confirmed that the update works for all tables when I run the code. However, after successfully updating the links, the execution is interrupted and without an error message. The `MsgBox (TableLinked)` that follows does not execute.

When the initial `If` statement evaluates to `False`, `MsgBox (TableLinked)` is executed, which tells me there is a hang up in my loop.

Any ideas as to what is going on here?

```
If Not GetBackend = "" Then
    For i = 0 To Db.TableDefs.Count
        If Not Db.TableDefs(i).Connect = "" Then
            Db.TableDefs(i).Connect = ";DATABASE=" & GetBackend
            Db.TableDefs(i).RefreshLink
            TableLinked = True
        End If
    Next i
Else
    TableLinked = False
End If

MsgBox (TableLinked)
```

**EDIT**

Well, I'll assume my subscript was out of range (although it just fails silently if so). When I do this in line 2 `For i = 0 To Db.TableDefs.Count - 1`, my code lives on after the loop. Anyone else ever have this happen? My solution still doesn't answer my question really cause I still don't know with a certainty what's breaking the code.

Comment: I seem to remember that most indexing that occurs in VBA starts with `1` (am I wrong?), yet not with `TableDefs`. Maybe the entire index is shifted to the left by `1`, which would explain why it works when subtracting by `1`. Whatever! :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The member items of the TableDefs collection are numbered starting with zero.  That means the index number of the last item is one less than the count of items.  Frankly I don't understand why your code is not throwing error #3265, *"Item not found in this collection"* ... because the equivalent of `TableDefs(TableDefs.Count)` attempts to reference a `TableDef` which does not exist.

Revise your code like this ...

```vb
'For i = 0 To Db.TableDefs.Count
Dim lngLastItem As Long
lngLastItem = (Db.TableDefs.Count - 1)
For i = 0 To lngLastItem
    If Not Db.TableDefs(i).Connect = "" Then
    ' and the rest ...
```

Comment: You're welcome, Scott.  I think you should still figure out why your original code failed silently.  Seems to me that should *not* happen, and I would be concerned that whatever suppressed the error message may bite you again in a different context.

Comment: I don't know where to begin to figure that out. Hasn't happened before...the offending code is in a `Public Function` that is called from a `Private Sub`, not that that should make a difference I would think.

Comment: Do you have an `On Error ...` statement somewhere ahead of that code?  Have you done anything with `DoCmd.SetWarnings` or `Echo`?

Comment: Ha, I do but I regularly comment my `On Error` statements out when debugging so it takes me directly to offending code. I just uncommented it and it did throw _Item not found in this Collection_. I remember now that I had seen it before I commented it out. User error!

Comment: Good.  Also look at Tools->Options in the VB Editor's main menu.  On the "General" tab of the Options dialog, you can choose "Break on All Errors".  That can be useful during debugging ... then you may not need to twiddle your existing `On Error` statements.  After done debugging, set the option back to "Break on Unhandled Errors".

Comment: Ah! That's handy! Thanks again!